# What is the effect of sampling rate on parameter estimation when fitting a markov state model to timeseries data?

Tags: time-series, estimation, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Let us say that I have some timeseries data, which can be described by a markov state model. And the time series has been sampled every $\Delta t$ time units. The sampling rate ($1/\Delta t$) must control how much infromation we can extract from the timeseries. A slower sampling rate will essentially miss faster transtions and consequently yield poor estimates of transition rates. Or if the sample rate is too slow compared to some transition rates some states might not even show up in the collected data. I know that the maximum likelihood estimator for transtion probabilities is given by

$ p_{ij}=n_{ij}/\sum_{j}n_{ij}$.

Here, $ p_{ij}$ is the transition probability from state i to j, and $n_{ij}$ is the number of transitions from i to j.

I am searching for a book where the effect of sampling frequency has been discussed systematically in this context and hopefully demonstrated with a simple example. Also, are there any analytical results which relate the error in the estimated parmeters to the sampling frequency?